# Not able to Identify element using following-sibling and preceding-sibling

Tags: selenium, xpath, appium, android-uiautomator

I want to identify the element ***TextView:Completed*** present in the 3rd 
linear layout

using the element ***TextView:Ashraf Mulla*** present in the 5th linear layout.

I tried below xpaths but it is not able to identify the COMPLETED element.

> Xpath 1 : "//android.widget.TextView[@text='Ashraf
>   Mulla']/../preceding-sibling::android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.TextView[@text='COMPLETED']"
>
> Xpath 2:
>   "//android.widget.TextView[@text='COMPLETED']/../following-sibling::android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.TextView[@text='Ashraf
>   Mulla']"

[UIAUTOMATORVIEWER_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNbmS.png)

Please help.

Comment: Provide the examples of xml files

Answer (score 0):

Below Xpath should work for you

```
"TextView[@text='Ashraf Mulla']/ancestor::android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.TextView[@text='COMPLETED']"
```